# how to console log or alert the data after posted in the server

Tags: javascript, react-redux, fetch

I was posting feedback data at my server and want to see the posted data in the alert.

```js
export const postFeedback = (
  firstname,
  lastname,
  telnum,
  email,
  agree,
  contactType,
  message
) => (dispatch) => {
  const newFeedback = {
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    telnum: telnum,
    email: email,
    agree: agree,
    contactType: contactType,
    message: message,
  };
  newFeedback.date = new Date().toISOString();

  return fetch(baseUrl + 'feedback', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(newFeedback),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  })
    .then(
      (response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          var error = new Error(
            'Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText
          );
          error.response = response;
          throw error;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        throw error;
      }
    )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => dispatch(addFeedback(response)))
    .then((response) => alert(response))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('post feedback', error.message);
      alert('Your feedback could not be posted\nError: ' + error.message);
    });
};
```

The data was posted correctly but in the alert I just see `[object Object]` Why? How could I console log or alert the data after posted in the server?

[image]

I heartily thank if anyone help me to figure out this.

Comment: have you tried changing `alert(response)` to `console.log(response)` because the response is an object and you on alert you will see `[object Object]` but on console.log you can see the object.

Comment: @falamiw check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may log the error with `JSON.stringify(obj)` as `alert` only displays text

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your object to a string, use `JSON.stringify(x)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

`[object Object]` is the stringified representation of an object.

either 
do `alert(JSON.stringify(error.message))`

OR

do `console.log(error.message)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert JSON into a string,
you can try this.

```
export const postFeedback = (
  firstname,
  lastname,
  telnum,
  email,
  agree,
  contactType,
  message
) => (dispatch) => {
  const newFeedback = {
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    telnum: telnum,
    email: email,
    agree: agree,
    contactType: contactType,
    message: message,
  };
  newFeedback.date = new Date().toISOString();

  return fetch(baseUrl + 'feedback', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(newFeedback),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  })
    .then(
      (response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          var error = new Error(
            'Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText
          );
          error.response = response;
          throw error;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        throw error;
      }
    )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => dispatch(addFeedback(response)))
    .then((response) => alert(JSON.stringify(response)))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('post feedback', error.message);
      alert('Your feedback could not be posted\nError: ' + error.message);
    });
};
```